# looping array and saving objects in NSMutableDictionary does not work?? logical problem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

It seems like i have a logical problem in this loop. I am trying to:

- Looping myKeys (from a dict) to find selected players
- Setting three BOOL parameters for the selected players (YES or NO) in an NSMutableArray (thePlayers)
- Updating a dict (selectedPlayerDict) with 'thePlayers' and 'myKeys'
- Empty thePlayers and do a new loop and the same thing

The individual players, when i select each player separately has the following parameters:

> selectedPlayerDict:{Hannah = (0,0,1);}
>
> selectedPlayerDict: {
>       AAAXXX =     (
>           1,
>           1,
>           1
>       );
>   }

When is select both, meaning the trigger on (if ([theObjects objectAtIndex:3] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES])), i get the following result with

> selectedPlayerDict: {
>       AAAXXX =     (
>           0,
>           0,
>           1,
>           1,
>           1,
>           1
>       );
>   Hannah =     (
>           0,
>           0,
>           1,
>           1,
>           1,
>           1
>       );
>   }

For the result above i use:

> //[thePlayers removeAllObjects];   //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

When i change and remove the commentary "//":

> [thePlayers removeAllObjects];   //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

I get the following result:

> selectedPlayerDict: {
>       AAAXXX =     (
>       );
>       Hannah =     (
>       );
>   }

The code i use is:

```
for (NSString *myKeys in allTheKeys) {
    theObjects = [playerDict valueForKey:myKeys];

    if ([theObjects objectAtIndex:3] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) {

        //[thePlayers addObject:myKeys]; 

        NSLog(@"Spelare: %@ är vald", myKeys);
        NSLog(@">>>><<<<");

        // Check what difficulties level
        if ([theObjects objectAtIndex:0] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) { //hard
            NSLog(@"Player have diff HARD");
            [thePlayers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]; //@"YES"];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Player have NOT diff HARD");
            [thePlayers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]; //@"NO"];
        }
        if ([theObjects objectAtIndex:1] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) { //medium
            NSLog(@"Player have diff MEDIUM");
            [thePlayers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]; //@"YES"];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Player have NOT diff MEDIUM");
            [thePlayers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]; //@"NO"];
        }
        if ([theObjects objectAtIndex:2] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) { //easy
            NSLog(@"Player have diff EASY");
            [thePlayers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]; //@"YES"];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Player have NOT diff EASY");
            [thePlayers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]]; //@"NO"];
        }
        [selectedPlayerDict setValue:thePlayers forKey:myKeys];
        [thePlayers removeAllObjects];   //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }

}
NSLog(@"selectedPlayerDict: %@", selectedPlayerDict);
```

I know i probably do something wrong here with the logic but i have tried now for hours to try to understand what i am doing wrong. I do not understand why the dic's objects is empty as i am "removeAllObjects" in the array in the end of the loop after i have updated the dict? I have tried "setObject:forKey:" but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing the same array for every key in selectedPlayerDict.  You would need to create a fresh array for each loop iteration; otherwise, the `removeAllObjects` is removing all objects from the single array that is the value for every key in your dictionary.

As a side note, I wonder if an `enum {Easy, Medium, Hard};` might serve your need better than 3 `BOOL`s -- what will happen if the user selects > 1 of the options?

Comment: I started with enum but as i tried to fix the problem i have been testing all kinds of things and ended up as it looks now. Will change that.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have already found the source of your problem, but here is a potential other problem:

```
[theObjects objectAtIndex:2] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
```

This appears to work because `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` is probably cached somewhere, however keep in mind that `==` compares object identity, not object equality. If you know that the objects in the `theObjects` array are NSNumber objects, you could use [`boolValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
if ([[theObjects objectAtIndex:2] boolValue])
   ...
```

If you are unsure whether the objects in the array are NSNumber instances, you can use the following:

```
if ([[theObjects objectAtIndex:2] isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]])
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are clearing the array that you just added to the dictionary.

Try this instead:

```
NSArray* tempArray = [thePlayers copy];
[selectedPlayerDict setValue:tempArray forKey:myKeys];   
[tempArray release];
```